Where to download OpenStack Base Charm and Bundle which perfect match OpenStack Ussuri
I am installing ubuntu 20.04 & openstack ussuri
But I just find OpenStack Base yoga/stable #79 on Charmhub
when juju info openstack-base via CLI,  find yoga/stable #79 also
I also checked github for history version， get bundle.yaml in openstack-base-focal-ussuri-ovn，but I can’t  find specific charm path in this bundle，“charm: cs:~openstack-charmers-next/ceph-mon” defined in almost evey history openstack base seems not a specific path
Questions:

where can I find and download OpenStack base which perfect match "OpenStack Ussuri", maybe named ussuri/stable(just like yoga/stable) or something else
Do I really need OpenStack base perfect match "OpenStack Ussuri"?
or can I just use yoga/stable #79 by setting "series: focal" and "source: cloud:focal-ussuri" in bundle.yaml? Does these two settings means I am installing OpenStack Ussuri even use yoga/stable #79?

thanks
